# CoreBluetooth Background Scan without service identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm working on a requirement where I need to initiate a background scan to search for BLE devices.

As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518986-scanforperipheralswithservices), you must specify the service IDs to scan in the background.

```
func scanForPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]?, 
            options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

What if I don't have the service UUIDs, but only the device UUIDs?

Is there a way to do a background scan by only using the device UUIDs?

Comment: No, there is no way to scan for a specific device id in the foreground or the background with Core Bluetooth.  If you have previously discovered a device, you can record its `identifier` and issue a `connect` to establish a connection when that device is seen, either in the background or the foreground.  Note that Core Bluetooth `identifier`s cannot be shared between ios devices; they are unique for each ios/peripheral pair.  If you can explain in a bit more detail what you are trying to achieve I can suggest more

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. Looks like I can only do a background scan with service UUIDs.